# Three.js memory leak with object wrapper

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is a little modified version of  "three.js webgl cameras." (got from examples)
I have created a wrapper div for the future canvas and a 'three_webgl' instance. 
(I create an instance for a new three_webgl, which is the original function instanced as an object).

As you can see there are two buttons one to create the instance and the animation and the other to stop the animation and delete the instance. 
I have a 'stop' control inside the animate loop.

Also  I have increased the number of points for the pointcloud (100 000) to measure the memory spent.

The problem I have is that delete works fine but I leave 10 000 KB 'lost'
You can play with create-start  / stop- delete and you can see how the memory grows and grows.

My question is how to delete the three  environment and data correctly. The goal is to avoid memory leaks.

I'm using the dev branch dated on 12 / 05, chrome 34.0 and Windows XP.

This is the code. (Maybe it is neccesary to change the tree paths for three and stats.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - cameras</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #808080;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;

                background-color: #000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;
                z-index: 100;
            }

            a {

                color: #0080ff;
            }

            b { color: lightgreen }

            #stats { position: absolute; top:0; left: 0 }
            #stats #fps { background: transparent !important }
            #stats #fps #fpsText { color: #777 !important }
            #stats #fps #fpsGraph { display: none }
        #apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 652px;
    height: 376px;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 54px;
    top: 95px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
        #apDiv2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 655px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 102;
    left: 53px;
    top: 490px;
    border: 1px red  solid;
}
        #apDiv3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 103;
    left: 54px;
    top: 52px;
}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>

        <div id="container"></div>
        <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - cameras<br/>
        <b>O</b> orthographic <b>P</b> perspective
        </div>
        <div id="apDiv1"></div>             
        <div id="apDiv2"></div>
        <div id="apDiv3">
        <input type="submit" name="b1" id="b1" value="crete-start"  onClick="new_webgl()">
        <input type="submit" name="b2" id="b2" value="stop-delete" onClick="del_webgl()">
        </div>


        <script src="tree/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="tree/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

        var webgl_true;
        try 
        { var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' ); 
        webgl_true =  !! window.WebGLRenderingContext && ( canvas.getContext( 'webgl' ) || canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl' ) ); }
        catch( e ) { webgl_true= false; } 
        THE_DIV2 = document.getElementById("apDiv2");
        THE_DIV2.innerHTML = "Webgl detector : "+webgl_true;                        
        </script>

   <script>

  var webgl;
  var renderer;
  var del_renderer = false;

  new_webgl = function ()     {  webgl = new three_webgl();  }

  var del_webgl = function () {  del_renderer = true;
  THE_DIV.parentNode.removeChild(THE_DIV);
  webgl = null;

//              THE_DIV.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  }



        three_webgl = function () {

        del_renderer = false;

        THE_DIV = document.createElement( 'div' );                      
        THE_DIV.style.height="100%";
        document.getElementById("apDiv1").appendChild(THE_DIV);


            var SCREEN_WIDTH  = THE_DIV.clientWidth;
            var SCREEN_HEIGHT = THE_DIV.clientHeight;

            var container, stats;
            var camera, scene,  mesh;
            var cameraRig, activeCamera, activeHelper;
            var cameraPerspective, cameraOrtho;
            var cameraPerspectiveHelper, cameraOrthoHelper;

            init();
            animate();

             function init () {

                //container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                //document.body.appendChild( container );


                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                //

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 2500;

                cameraPerspective = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 150, 1000 );

                cameraPerspectiveHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper( cameraPerspective );
                scene.add( cameraPerspectiveHelper );

                //

                cameraOrtho = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH / - 2, 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / - 2, 150, 1000 );

                cameraOrthoHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper( cameraOrtho );
                scene.add( cameraOrthoHelper );

                //

                activeCamera = cameraPerspective;
                activeHelper = cameraPerspectiveHelper;


                // counteract different front orientation of cameras vs rig

                cameraOrtho.rotation.y = Math.PI;
                cameraPerspective.rotation.y = Math.PI;

                cameraRig = new THREE.Object3D();

                cameraRig.add( cameraPerspective );
                cameraRig.add( cameraOrtho );

                scene.add( cameraRig );

                //

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100, 16, 8 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true } ) );
                scene.add( mesh );

                var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 16, 8 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true } ) );
                mesh2.position.y = 150;
                mesh.add( mesh2 );

                var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 16, 8 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff, wireframe: true } ) );
                mesh3.position.z = 150;
                cameraRig.add( mesh3 );

                //

                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

                for ( var i = 0; i < 100000; i ++ ) {

                    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                    vertex.x = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 2000 );
                    vertex.y = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 2000 );
                    vertex.z = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 2000 );

                    geometry.vertices.push( vertex );

                }

                var particles = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { color: 0x888888 } ) );
                scene.add( particles );

                //


                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
                renderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
                THE_DIV.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                renderer.autoClear = false;

                //

                stats = new Stats();
                THE_DIV2.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );

            }

            //

            function onKeyDown ( event ) {

                switch( event.keyCode ) {

                    case 79: /*O*/

                        activeCamera = cameraOrtho;
                        activeHelper = cameraOrthoHelper;

                        break;

                    case 80: /*P*/

                        activeCamera = cameraPerspective;
                        activeHelper = cameraPerspectiveHelper;

                        break;

                }

            };

            //

            function onWindowResize( event ) {

                SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
                SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

                renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

                camera.aspect = 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                cameraPerspective.aspect = 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
                cameraPerspective.updateProjectionMatrix();

                cameraOrtho.left   = - 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
                cameraOrtho.right  =   0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
                cameraOrtho.top    =   SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
                cameraOrtho.bottom = - SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
                cameraOrtho.updateProjectionMatrix();

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                if (!(del_renderer))
                { requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                  render();
                }
                stats.update();
                if (del_renderer) {renderer=null;}
            }


            function render() {

                var r = Date.now() * 0.0005;

                mesh.position.x = 700 * Math.cos( r );
                mesh.position.z = 700 * Math.sin( r );
                mesh.position.y = 700 * Math.sin( r );

                mesh.children[ 0 ].position.x = 70 * Math.cos( 2 * r );
                mesh.children[ 0 ].position.z = 70 * Math.sin( r );

                if ( activeCamera === cameraPerspective ) {

                    cameraPerspective.fov = 35 + 30 * Math.sin( 0.5 * r );
                    cameraPerspective.far = mesh.position.length();
                    cameraPerspective.updateProjectionMatrix();

                    cameraPerspectiveHelper.update();
                    cameraPerspectiveHelper.visible = true;

                    cameraOrthoHelper.visible = false;

                } else {

                    cameraOrtho.far = mesh.position.length();
                    cameraOrtho.updateProjectionMatrix();

                    cameraOrthoHelper.update();
                    cameraOrthoHelper.visible = true;

                    cameraPerspectiveHelper.visible = false;

                }

                cameraRig.lookAt( mesh.position );

                renderer.clear();

                activeHelper.visible = false;

                renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
                renderer.render( scene, activeCamera );

                activeHelper.visible = true;

                renderer.setViewport( SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }


        }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nobody wants to answer ? Have I to use the dispose methods? It is not enought to delete the whole THREE object ? Can anybody test this ? @westlangley ??

Comment: It's probably a bit late, but I think you can clean up the memory by calling .dispose on your PointCloud's geometry object, which should deallocate any buffers.